# Div 100% height of page responsive

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have had a search but can't find exactly what I want to achieve, in CSS anyway I'm not sure if there could be a jQuery script that could help.

I want to create a div on my website which fills the entire height of the page (no further than the area below the scroll just the first area of the screen filled vertically). I want this to adjust to the height of device so on a desktop and iPhone for example the whole screen vertical height is filled.

I'm not sure if I can post websites but this is the look I'm after http://alexcerezo.com

Comment: try google. You need to set every parent of the div you want to fill the screen to `height: 100%` including html and body.

Comment: Won't that set the height to the whole height of the page, not just the height the screen fills initially minus any scrolling height?

Answer (score 3):

Do this!

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"> Content </div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv
{
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The max and min height ensure that it will never occupy more or less than the height of the window (this includes if they shrink the browser to smaller than screen-height )!

:)

EDIT: Nick's comment is also incredibly important, you all parent divs including body and html must also have min-max-height set to 100%, otherwise the div will size to 100% of it's parents height.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your div to have full height of the page you can do:

```
$('div').css('height',$('body').height());
```

or if you want it to be full height of the browser, do:

```
$('div').css('height',$(window).height());
```

Just execute any of these lines once the document is ready i.e `$(document).ready()`. You can however, set the height by using height:100% in CSS by nesting the div correctly and having the right height set to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

First, you could try using `height:100vh;` where `vh`represents the viewport height. `100vh` represents 100% of the viewport height. (If you ever happen to need viewport width, use vw.) This can cause problems when the element has margins, and things can get annoying.

The other method, which is probably better:

```
top:0;
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
```

This will ignore all margins and padding, and the div will take up the whole height of the screen without causing too many problems. If you need to, you can also use `left:0;` and `right:0;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbTr6/)